# SwiftLint config in dependency source conflicts with SwiftLint in main project

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, swiftlint, apollo-ios

I have a project that uses SwiftLint and Swift Package Manager. One of the packages I'm pulling in (Apollo) is in turn pulling in another framework (Stencil). *That* framework (Stencil) has a swiftlint.yml file in its source with a specific `swiftlint_version` set.

When I attempt to build my project, my SwiftLint is failing because the `swiftlint_version` specified in Stencil's source is being honoured and is different to what I have installed (I have a more recent version installed).

Do I have my project set up incorrectly to use SwiftLint? All I have is the yml file in my source and SwiftLint installed via Homebrew, then my project runs SwiftLint via a script in the build phases.

Answer (score 0):

Well I realised what I was doing wrong just after posting the question.

I had to add the `Codegen` path created as part of the Apollo setup process into the `excluded` list in my `swiftlint.yml` file.